# Why select not give all columns? - pyspark

Tags: select, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can you help me to understand why I am getting:

> "cannot resolve '`actual_date`' given input columns: [general_id, payments_803_all]
> ?
> actual_date is in the MAIN_TABLE and it was selected by SELECT.

```
df = df_MAIN_TABLE.select(concat(lpad(col('id_1'), 3, '0'), lpad(col('id_2'), 3, '0'),
                                  lpad(col('id_3'), 7, '0')).alias('general_id'), 'payment','actual_date')\
                                  .where((col('payment_code')==803) & (col('actual_date').between(date_from1,end_of_month)))\
                                  .groupBy('general_id').agg(sum('payment').alias('payments_803_all'))\
                                  .agg(max('actual_date').alias('last_action_date'))\
                                  .withColumn('validity_date', lit(end_of_month))
```

Comment: You need to calculate the max date in the first agg with the payment sum. Try this: `.agg(F.sum('payment').alias('payments_803_all'), F.max('actual_date').alias('last_action_date'))`

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the `actual_date` to `last_action_date` and `actual_date` is not part in the **group by**.

So there is no reference for `actual_date` column to get the `actual_date` include this column in the groupBy.

**`Example:`**

Try to modify your groupBy condition as below and then you can get the `actual_date` column.

```
.groupBy('general_id','actual_date').agg(sum('payment').alias('payments_803_all'),max('actual_date').alias('last_action_date'))\
```

Comment: is it the way if I need 'last_action_date' be grouped by 'general_id'?

Comment: max('actual_date').alias('last_action_date')   - not working, I am getting error - 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'max'

Comment: @Ann, Add some sample data and expected output so that its easier for us to understand..!!

Comment: Actually there is no need to group by `actual_date`.